# EL - show all elements of a list but the last one

Tags: jsf-2, el

I'm creating a simple breadcrumb navigation bar in JSF 2.
The list of elements is inside a List and now it's displayed using

```
<ui:repeat xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    value="#{navigation.breadCrumb}" var="topic">
#{topic}>>
        </ui:repeat>
```

and it appears as

```
home>> topic1>> topic2>>
```

now I'd like to show the last topic in bold and to avoid displaying the last ">>", I thought that would be easy but didn't find an easy way to do it using EL, not even with Spring EL. It's possible to start from a specific index using the `offset` attribute, but there's not an equivalent one for the superior limit.

Is there a simple way to do so using only EL or is necessary to change the bean below?
In general, is possible to get the index of the element in addition to the element itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [varStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html):

```
<ui:repeat xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
           value="#{navigation.breadCrumb}"
           var="topic"
           varStatus="_status">
  <h:outputText value="#{topic} &gt;&gt;"
                rendered="#{!_status.last}" />
  <h:outputText value="#{topic}"
                styleClass="special"
                rendered="#{_status.last}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

*Note: untested code.*